# split delimited values in dataframe into multidimensional array in R

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe where some cells have numbers, others have NA, and others have multiple numbers separated by commas (all values are character class due to commas). I would like to "push" the values from cells that have multiple comma separated numbers into a new layer but preserve their column/row placement to make a multidimensional array with only one number in each cell, and the rest filled with NAs.

Example input:

```
         col1           col2 col3
row1      814             NA   NA
row2 814,9732           7245 4928
row3       NA 4921,8288,4923   NA
```

Desired output:

```
, , 1

     [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  
[1,] "814" "NA"   "NA"  
[2,] "814" "7245" "4928"
[3,] "NA"  "4921" "NA"  

, , 2

     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
[1,] "NA"   "NA"   "NA"
[2,] "9732" "NA"   "NA"
[3,] "NA"   "8288" "NA"

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]   [,3]
[1,] "NA" "NA"   "NA"
[2,] "NA" "NA"   "NA"
[3,] "NA" "4923" "NA"
```

I've tried going along and using a version of `lapply(my.df, function(x) strsplit(x, ","))` but it results in a strange list-within-dataframe structure that I can't figure out how to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I get the feeling there must be a better way of doing this, but this works:

```
library(abind)

dflist <- lapply(df, strsplit, ',')
maxlen <- max(sapply(dflist, lengths))

out <- lapply(seq_len(maxlen), 
              function(i) sapply(dflist, function(x) sapply(x, `[`, i)))

do.call(abind, c(out, along = 3))
```

Output:

```
, , 1

     col1  col2   col3  
[1,] "814" NA     NA    
[2,] "814" "7245" "4928"
[3,] NA    "4921" NA    

, , 2

     col1   col2   col3
[1,] NA     NA     NA  
[2,] "9732" NA     NA  
[3,] NA     "8288" NA  

, , 3

     col1 col2   col3
[1,] NA   NA     NA  
[2,] NA   NA     NA  
[3,] NA   "4923" NA
```

Data Used:

```
df <- fread("
         col1           col2 col3
row1      814             NA   NA
row2 814,9732           7245 4928
row3       NA 4921,8288,4923   NA
")[, -1, with = F]
df[, col3 := as.character(col3)]
setDF(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it worked great on my real data! It does seem like there should be a simpler way, but your approach is what came to my mind first too, I just got stuck on all the nested applys. Good use of abind